# Firebase Phone Auth - PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber() completion handler is not running

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) for authenticating the user via a code sent to a mobile number. I've double checked each step to make sure I didn't miss something for setting up Firebase and FirebaseAuth up front.

**Expected behavior**: The completion handler should run, printing the "Inside the verifyPhoneNumber completion handler." message, as well as (1) the "Got an error trying to verify the phone number." message OR (2) "Verification ID is  OR (3) "Verification ID is nil, but no error was reported".

**Actual behavior**: None of my print statements are running, which leads me to believe that the completion handler itself isn't running.

I have already verified that code right before this call is running just fine, so my best guess is that something about setting up Firebase/FirebaseAuth isn't right. My app builds successfully and I have tested this on both Simulator as well as an actual device with the same results.

```
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(
        formattedPhoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil)
    { (verificationID, error) in
        print("Inside the verifyPhoneNumber completion handler.")

        if let error = error {
            print("Got an error trying to verify the phone number.")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let verificationID = verificationID {
            print("Verification ID is \(verificationID)")
        } else {
            print("Verification ID is nil, but no error was reported.")
        }
    }
```